# Detect launch of an external application

Tags: vb.net, vba, process, window, detect

I would like to know if it is possible to detect when the window of a named external application is launched and how to.

Example:
When firefox or notepad(preferably by process name. Not notepad.exe for example) is ran, minimize my application.

Answer (score 1):

```
For each p as process in process.GetProcesses()
If p.processname = "notepad" then
'Do something
Else
'Do Else Something
End If
Next
```

Comment: Well that will do 'something else' for EVERY process in the list that is NOT 'notepad' ...

Comment: Not if you leave 'Do Else Something commented out.

Comment: Yea, right... but then you could relable it: 'do nothing
// Also if there are several processes of notepad running the 'do something part will be runned as many times... of course you could leave that one commented out aswell :)

Comment: That was careless in my part, good point, may i edit and put an Exit For after the 'Do something? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here two ways, that would work:

```
 Dim plist() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")
 If plist.Length > 0 Then
      ' notepad is running at least once
 Else
      ' notepad is not running
 End If
```

or

```
    Dim notepadRunning As Boolean = False
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If p.ProcessName = "notepad" Then notepadRunning = True
    Next
    If notepadRunning Then
        ' notepad is running at least once
    Else
        'notepad is not running
    End If
```

Note: the second way is just a glorified version of the first...